# How to enable and use WebView for iOS Automation in Appium

Tags: c#, webview, automation, appium, appium-ios

I am trying to automate hybrid app using Appium developed by Ionic2/Angular2/Typescript.

When I am trying to identify element I am able to see element in WebView in Appium Inspector but when I try to identify them using script it is throwing error.

```
An element could not be identified using given search parameter.

error: Invalid locator strategy: partial link text
```

I am trying to identify elemnet through Xpath, name, linkText but I am not able to do so.

I also enable webview in capabilities by adding

```
capabilities.SetCapability("autoWebView", "true");
```

I am using C# for automating. Can anybody provide the solution?

When I use Xpath it shows An unknown server side error occured while processing the command (Original error: connect ECONNREFUSED)

Above error is displayed when I call `var contextNames= driver.Contexts;` after setting the above capability. Do I also need to set capability for browser???

Answer (score 0):

Two things :

**1**. Ensure `setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled` is set to true in your webview code.

**2**. Before accessing the elements on a webview, switch the context and back after the operations. Something similar to the below code in Java for switching to *WEBVIEW* :

```
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
String setContext = contextNames.toArray()[1].toString();
driver.context(setContext);// set context to WEBVIEW_com.my.package
```

Please do read the following for [What exactly do autoWebview does?](https://discuss.appium.io/t/what-does-the-autowebview-desired-capability-really-do/69/2?u=namannigam14)

For dot-net client, a similar code goes as :

```
var contextNames = driver.GetContexts(); //correction to your code 
driver.SetContext(contextNames[1]); // for webview_1, for native_view 0
```

Comment: @@nullpointer where do i need to set this 'setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled' property. Do I need to ask my developer to set it in their code and then build the ipa/apk??

Comment: @SurajGupta : yes thats set into the application code.

Comment: I checked it in development code and it is already set as true.
Can you comment why I am getting below error when trying to retrieve all contexts using `var contextNames=driver.Contexts;`

Error is **An unknown server side error occured while processing the command (Original error: connect ECONNREFUSED)**

Comment: @SurajGupta : probably you need to change your code, edited in the answer

Comment: Also as I went through the dot net client has had changes where you can directly set the context with something like :
`driver = new AndroidDriver...
driver.Context = "NATIVE_APP";`

Comment: @@nullpointer driver.Context = "NATIVE_APP"; is working fine but Other Context i.e. "WEBVIEW_1", "WEBVIEW_2", "WEB_VIEW" are not woking. driver.Contexts should have given the list but above error is popping up. How can I get the views in which my app is?? Striggling with it..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112034/discussion-between-nullpointer-and-suraj-gupta).

Comment: @Suraj : as already updated in the code in answer as well, `driver.GetContexts()` would give you the list of contexts
Also remember the context name for WEBVIEWs generally have the package name appended in the format `WEBVIEW_<app package name>`

Answer (score 0):

**1) First option**

Below code will help to handle Native app to webview

```
public void acceptalert(){
    Set<String> contextNames = idriver.getContextHandles();

    System.out.println(contextNames);

    for (String contextName : contextNames) {
      if (contextName.contains("NATIVE_APP")) {
        Reporter.log("Reaching to Native App", true);
        idriver.context(contextName);
        idriver.findElementByName("Open").click();
        Reporter.log("Clicking Open to naviagte to Native APP", true);
      }
      else{
        Reporter.log("Not found", true);
      }
    }
}
```

**2) Second option :**

```
try {
            //idriver.context("WEBVIEW_2");

            Set<String> contextNames1 = idriver.getContextHandles();
            for (String winHandle : idriver.getWindowHandles())
            {
                if (winHandle.contains("WEBVIEW_24")){
                    ((AppiumDriver) idriver).context(winHandle);
                    System.out.println("Switched to " + winHandle);
                    idriver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
                    idriver.findElementByName("Open").click();
                }

                else if (winHandle.contains("NATIVE_APP")) {
                    ((AppiumDriver) idriver).context(winHandle);
                    idriver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
                    System.out.println("Switched to " + winHandle);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Even after using

```
capabilities.SetCapability("autoWebView", "true");
```

We need to access proxy to handle webview

```
Set<String> contextNames = idriver.getContextHandles();

    System.out.println(contextNames);

    for (String contextName : contextNames) {
      if (contextName.contains("NATIVE_APP")) {
        Reporter.log("Reaching to Native App", true);
        idriver.context(contextName);
        idriver.findElementByName("Open").click();
        Reporter.log("Clicking Open to naviagte to Native APP", true);
      }
      else{
        Reporter.log("Not found", true);
      }
    }
```

or try to ru proxy to handle webview -- just a hack

Ru below on terminal

```
ios_webkit_debug_proxy -c abad62540cbfc9f2af5c154985420a856e:27753 -d
```