# Not able to identify element in WEBVIEW in iOS hyprid app automation using Appium on real device

Tags: automation, appium, hybrid-mobile-app, inspector, appium-ios

I was trying to automate the hybrid app build using ionic2/Angular2 and typescript.

I am using C# for code writing.
test are in BDD - specflow
Versions:
iOS:9.3.1
Xcode: 7.3
Appium: 1.4.13

I am not able to identify elements after swtiching Context to WEBVIEW.

Calling IOSDriver using below code

```
private IOSDriver<IOSElement> driver = null;

public IOSDriver<IOSElement> GetDriver(string platformVersion, string deviceName, string udid ,string appPath, string serverUri)
{
    Capabilities iosCapabilities = new Capabilities();
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = iosCapabilities.Get(platformVersion, deviceName, udid, appPath);
    driver = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(new Uri(serverUri), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Constants.DriverWaitTime));
    driver.Manage ().Timeouts ().ImplicitlyWait (TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Constants.ImplicitWaitTime));

    var contextNames = driver.Contexts;
    driver.Context = contextNames[1];

    driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(locator)).Click();

}
```

Setting Capabilities as

```
private DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

capabilities.SetCapability ("appium-version", Constants.AppiumVersion);
capabilities.SetCapability ("platformName", Constants.PlatformName);
capabilities.SetCapability("autoWebView", "true");
capabilities.SetCapability("browserName", "iOS");
capabilities.SetCapability ("platformVersion", Constants.PlatformVersion);
capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", deviceName);
capabilities.SetCapability("app", appPath);
capabilities.SetCapability("udid", udid);
```

Am I setting the capabilities in correct way?

1. Solution tried:

   1. I checked using browserName capbility as blank/safari but didn't worked
   2. Also, I installed ios-webkit-debug-proxy and started proxy using terminal in background on my mac
2. Problem is i am not able to identify elements in WEBVIEW.

**What I am doing**

After launching the app, in appium inspector I am able
    to see all the elements and I am trying to click on textbox to enter
    some value

Xpath of textbox(as i can view in appium inspector window): **"//UIAApplication[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGZWr.png)/UIAWindow[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGZWr.png)/UIAScrollView[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faWEH.png)/UIAWebView[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGZWr.png)/UIATextField[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGZWr.png)**"

`var contextNames = driver.Contexts`

is giving me list to views(In my case 2 views: NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_1)
WebView context is dynamically updating from 1,2,3 and so on..

As soon as I call

```
diver.Context=contextNames[1]; //setting context to WEBVIEW
```

and refresh the appium inspector I am not able to see/identify single element.Everything goes away.

Why I am not able to see/identify elements after switching to webview. (Note: As soon as I Switch back to driver.Context="NATIVE_APP" every element becomes visible in appium inspector but still I am not able to click)

**It shows error as "An element could not be located using given search parameter"**

Manually also when I try to tap or sendkeys using appium inspector it is not letting me do so(after lauching tha app manually using inspector button). What is the issue here. Help would be highly appreciated

Screenshot of Appium inspector:

[image]

Error message as displayed in appium window:

[image]

Here are the full logs of Appium(ERROR)

[Link of Appium logs when not able to identify elements in WEBVIEW](http://www.wepaste.com/Appium%20logs/)

Comment: please split this into sub parts, seems too long to be answered at once OR format properly to get to know your queries

Comment: Basically I am trying to identify the elements present in webview(my app is hybrid) after swtiching from default context to "WEBVIEW" but not able to do so

Answer (score 1):

1. Continues of from here : [How to enable and use WebView for iOS Automation in Appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37226537/how-to-enable-and-use-webview-for-ios-automation-in-appium)

Try and use the following code to switch contexts :

```
var contextNames = driver.GetContexts(); //correction to your code 
driver.SetContext(contextNames[1]);
```

2. You don't necessarily need the following capability while using appium :

   ```
   capabilities.SetCapability("browserName", "iOS"); //can be removed from code as well
   ```
3. I am guessing you might be trying to use Appium Inspector along with running/debugging your tests. In which case you might not be able to use both the instances. Please look into the appium server logs for details on this.

Comment: 1. For C# I researched and found that implementation for driver.GetContexts() has been changed. Now it's driver.Contexts and driver.Context
2. I tried with that also but no progress
3. Didn't get what you are trying to say. What does "Appium Inspector along with running/debugging your tests" mean

Comment: @SurajGupta : okay I hope you are successful in changing the context at the first and what I meant was you can run only one session using appium serve at a time which can be either Appium Inspector OR your tests using dot-net-client.

Comment: Yes Using IOSdriver I was able to change the context successfully. Facing issue while element identification.

Comment: @SurajGupta please share the code you are using to select the element along with a appium inspector screenshot of the same. Also please add it to the question itself, makes more sense.

Comment: @@nullpointer screenshot added. Code is present in question. Just setting up capabilities and calling driver to launch the app to identify one element.

Comment: @SurajGupta : If that be the case, this seems to be an appium inspector's issue. I don't think the code using the client comes into play here.

Comment: Would you recommend me to update Appium 1.4.13 to latest 1.5.2??

Comment: @SurajGupta : cannot comment on any pros and cons of updates to inspector as of now. but you can give it a try for sure.

Comment: updated but still not luck :/ Is this the bug in appium where appium is not able to automate ionic apps because when I see HTML page of the Webview page I can see ionic specific tags in HTML

Comment: Found workaround. Appium is not able to identify `//ion-input[@name='abc']` tags instead i used step by step process where
1. Using property get the attribute value
2. Using that attribute try to click on element

Answer (score 0):

***I think you have to Set up UICatalog in Appium***

1. Copy this link in xcode : https://github.com/appium/ios-uicatalog
2. Search the repository where we have the UICatalog.app installed 
   Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UICatalog-bhmtevqhmgarbcgnqybxttbkqfvn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UICatalog.app
3. Copy it into app path in Appium ios settings

Comment: @@Emna Do you mean [here](http://testdroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Screen-Shot-2015-12-08-at-13.27.32.png) Then were should I put the .ipa file path of my hybrid app??

Comment: In my case i did that because it's an hybrid site to test not an app and it works fine for me .

Comment: Then how appium knows which hybrid .ipa app to open

Comment: I told you i test with a site so i only give the url in my test to my site ;)
may be not the same case as me !

Answer (score 0):

1) While access ios webview -- using getcontextHandles we can achieve

Set contextNames = idriver.getContextHandles();

```
System.out.println(contextNames);

for (String contextName : contextNames) {
  if (contextName.contains("NATIVE_APP")) {
    Reporter.log("Reaching to Native App", true);
    idriver.context(contextName);
    sleepfor(1000);
    idriver.findElementByName("Open").click();
    Reporter.log("Clicking Open to naviagte to Native APP", true);
  }
  else{
    Reporter.log("Not found", true);
  }
}
```

2) If above context doesn't work -- try to run iproxy 
run this in terminal -- ios_webkit_debug_proxy -c deviceID:27753 -d 
deviceID -- to get device id (instruments -s devices)

Comment: Thanks for answering. This is not the solution nut. I have mentioned your solution in my question itself. 

Solution: As app was build in ionic2/angular2 I had to encapsulate all ionic specific element to normal tags because webview is not able to understand ionic specific elements and hence not able to perform any action on the same. Example: <ionic-button> tag to <button> and so on.. This resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

"Hi,
I was also facing the same issue in clicking a field on an iOS hybrid app. I tried different approaches like TouchAction, Action, and so on.

After carefully debugging the code, I found that the context change was done successfully, but the click action was not performing. The execution then proceeded to the next step. So, I tried changing the locator for the WebElement. Although the previous locator was working for Android and mWeb, I found that one of my CSS locators worked for clicking the field.

Subsequently, I tried adding CSS locators for other WebElements, and my script worked fine.

Note: try to use relative CSS locators, e.g., tagName[attribute='value'], div[class='bold-text'].

```
    @FindAll({
@FindBy(css = "div[css='2']"),
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@class=\"label-container return--location\"]//*[@class=\"airport-info--code\"]")
})
private WebElement dropOffCityCode;
```

I hope this might help all of you."

Comment: Why is this entire answer quoted? Did you copy it from somewhere?

Comment: corrected Grammars from Grammarly.