# Executing 'find_element' atom in default context error while trying to sendkeys in WEBVIEW of hybrid app using Appium

Tags: automation, appium, hybrid-mobile-app, inspector, appium-ios

After launching the hybrid app build in Ionic2/Angular2/Typescript, I am changing the context using below code:

```
var contextNames=driver.Contexts;
driver.Context= contextNames[1]; //changing context to WEBVIEW

driver.FindElementByXPath("locator").Click(); //getting error on this step
```

After switching context I tried to use xpath from Appium inspector as well as from safari develop window

Appium Xpath = //UIAApplication[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276566/not-able-to-identify-element-in-webview-in-ios-hyprid-app-automation-using-appiu/37277185?noredirect=1#comment62117055_37277185)/UIAWindow[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276566/not-able-to-identify-element-in-webview-in-ios-hyprid-app-automation-using-appiu/37277185?noredirect=1#comment62117055_37277185)/UIAButton[2]
Safari Xpath = //*[@placeholder='Username' and @class='ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid']

As I am working on hybrid app

```
   1.  I installed ios_webkit_debug_proxy on mac 
   2. Started the same on 27753 port
   3. In machine's mac browser localhost:27753 gives the link
   4. Clicked on the link which displays the elements of the webview app which is currently running on connected device
   5. Took above safari xpath from here
```

For more details on the capabilities used and screenshot related to the error please navigate to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276566/not-able-to-identify-element-in-webview-in-ios-hyprid-app-automation-using-appiu/37277185?noredirect=1#comment62117055_37277185)

Getting below error

```
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Executing 'find_element' atom in default context
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending javascript command
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Remote debugger data sent [{"method":"Runtime.evaluate","params":{"objectGroup":"console","includeCommandLineAPI":true,"doNotPauseOnExceptionsAndMuteConsole":true,"expression":"(function(){return function(){function h(a){return...]

info: [debug] [REMOTE] Debugger web socket received data: {"result":{"result":{"type":"string","value":"{\"status\":0,\"value\":null}"},"wasThrown":false},"id":53}
info: [debug] Waited for 29725ms so far
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the context into NATIVE then switch back to WEBVIEW

```
/* Code for context to find the View used in application */
Set contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String contextName : contextNames) {
    System.out.println(contextName);
    if (contextName.contains("WEBVIEW")){
    driver.context(contextName);
    }
}
```

Comment: `var contextNames=driver.Contexts;
driver.Context= contextNames[1]; //changing context to WEBVIEW`

I am using C# for coding. They have changed the way we change context in C#. I have already change the context using above code