# Can we automate hybrid iOS app build in Ionic using only Appium(i.e. without protractor)

Tags: ionic-framework, protractor, appium, ui-automation, hybrid-mobile-app

We are building an hybrid app in Ionic2/Angular2 and typescript and we are trying to write functional test automation of the same using Appium + Specflow(as test language) in C#.

Is it possible to automate Ionic app using Appium(without protractor) only??

I am planning to keep functional test project independent of development environment. Hence not planning to use Protractor + Appium

I was trying to automate ionic hybrid app using Appium only but facing issues([issue1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276566/not-able-to-identify-element-in-webview-in-ios-hyprid-app-automation-using-appiu/37304752?noredirect=1#comment62161463_37304752) and [issue2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276566/not-able-to-identify-element-in-webview-in-ios-hyprid-app-automation-using-appiu)).

Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use testng + java with appium ;)

Comment: you can use webdriver js (see https://github.com/appium/sample-code/blob/master/sample-code/examples/node/ios-safari.js), but then you have to handle all the angular stuff at your own, e.g. ensure no outstanding request is happening

Comment: @@Emna  I tried but not able to identify the ionic tags.. have you tried automating hybrid ionic iOS app

Comment: @hypery2k Have you tried it because when I do appium is not able to identify ionic html tags and instead gives error : **An element could not be located using given search parameter**

Comment: that's kind of the issue what I meant with you have to handle it for your own. Why not justing using protractor? You can use it with Appium

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps reason why your elements picked are not recognized is that you have not enabled autowebview. By default autowebview is set to false. I recommend to add in your capabilities appium file a 'autowebview = true'

Comment: I followed all the steps... If you get chance please have a look into both the links which I have shared in the last line of question. thanks